# How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a JavaScript widget which provides standard extension points. One of them is the `beforecreate` function. It should return `false` to prevent an item from being created.

I've added an Ajax call into this function using jQuery:

```
beforecreate: function (node, targetNode, type, to) {
  jQuery.get('http://example.com/catalog/create/' + targetNode.id + '?name=' + encode(to.inp[0].value),

  function (result) {
    if (result.isOk == false) 
        alert(result.message);
  });
}
```

But I want to prevent my widget from creating the item, so I should return `false` in the mother-function, not in the callback. Is there a way to perform a synchronous AJAX request using jQuery or any other in-browser API?

Comment: The proper way to solve that would be to rewrite your widget's extension point use promises. This way would easily allow you to set up an asynchronous action (like an ajax request) as `beforecreate`.

Comment: I propose the Sajak function.  Do we have a letter T?  Yes vanna, give me 3 T's.

Comment: @Kos is spot on. Sync XHR is not required here

Comment: If people ask me for 1 piece of advice when starting javascript, I say: embrace the asynchronous character of javascript, don't try ty fight that.

Comment: You can try using http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Comment: This question is like asking "how do I store my user passwords in plain text?" Sure there is an answer, but don't do it.

Comment: these comments are like "I know what you asked but since i don't like the way you do it, i'm going to not give a useful answer and just tell you to rethink your life choices".  Sometimes synchronous calls are necessary.

Answer (score 1251, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): you specify the **asynchronous** option to be **false** to get a synchronous Ajax request. Then your callback can set some data before your mother function proceeds.

Here's what your code would look like if changed as suggested:

```
beforecreate: function (node, targetNode, type, to) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/catalog/create/' + targetNode.id + '?name=' + encode(to.inp[0].value),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.isOk == false) alert(result.message);
        },
        async: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly, it is impossible to use get(), post(), load() for synchronous calls. Only ajax() have "async" parameter, which can be set to "false".

Comment: @SLA80 Nope. Since jQuery 1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849686/how-to-change-ajax-default-settings

Comment: Note that the use of `async: false` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest?rq=1). If you use it, you will see the following message in the console: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"

Comment: Refer this: ```https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-promisify-an-ajax-call/```

Also you can use ```jqxhr``` variable which is returned or you can create a promise at the point of Invocation & call the function within that.

Answer (score 276):

You can put the jQuery's Ajax setup in synchronous mode by calling

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

And then perform your Ajax calls using `jQuery.get( ... );`

Then just turning it on again once

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

I guess it works out the same thing as suggested by @Adam, but it might be helpful to someone that does want to reconfigure their `jQuery.get()` or `jQuery.post()` to the more elaborate `jQuery.ajax()` syntax.

Answer (score 149):

Excellent solution! I noticed when I tried to implement it that if I returned a value in the success clause, it came back as undefined. I had to store it in a variable and return that variable. This is the method I came up with:

```
function getWhatever() {
  // strUrl is whatever URL you need to call
  var strUrl = "", strReturn = "";

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: strUrl,
    success: function(html) {
      strReturn = html;
    },
    async:false
  });

  return strReturn;
}
```

Comment: This is a Synchronous call (async:false).

Answer (score 94):

All of these answers miss the point that doing an Ajax call with async:false will cause the browser to hang until the Ajax request completes. Using a flow control library will solve this problem without hanging up the browser. Here is an example with [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js):

```
beforecreate: function(node,targetNode,type,to) {

    Frame(function(next)){

        jQuery.get('http://example.com/catalog/create/', next);
    });

    Frame(function(next, response)){

        alert(response);
        next();
    });

    Frame.init();
}
```

Answer (score 55):

```
function getURL(url){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}


//example use
var msg=getURL("message.php");
alert(msg);
```

Answer (score 31):

Keep in mind that if you're doing a cross-domain Ajax call (by using [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506306/56621)) - you **can't** do it synchronously, the `async` flag will be ignored by jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "testserver.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp', // jsonp
    async: false //IGNORED!!
});
```

For JSONP-calls you could use:

1. Ajax-call to your own domain - and do the cross-domain call server-side
2. Change your code to work asynchronously
3. Use a "function sequencer" library like Frame.js (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365952/1785164))
4. Block the UI instead of blocking the execution (this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134810/1785164)) (my favourite way)

Answer (score 31):

Note: You shouldn't use `async: false` due to this warning messages:

> Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Chrome even warns about this in the console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

This could break your page if you are doing something like this since it could stop working any day.

If you want to do it a way that still feels like if it's synchronous but still don't block then you should use async/await and probably also some ajax that is based on promises like the new [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API

```
async function foo() {
  var res = await fetch(url)
  console.log(res.ok)
  var json = await res.json()
  console.log(json)
}
```

**Edit**
chrome is working on [Disallowing sync XHR in page dismissal](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4664843055398912) when the page is being navigated away or closed by the user. This involves beforeunload, unload, pagehide and visibilitychange.

if this is your use case then you might want to have a look at [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) instead

It is also possible for the page to disable sync req with either http headers or iframe's allow attribute

Answer (score 18):

I used the answer given by Carcione and modified it to use JSON.

```
 function getUrlJsonSync(url){

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false
    });

    // 'async' has to be 'false' for this to work
    var response = {valid: jqxhr.statusText,  data: jqxhr.responseJSON};

    return response;
}    

function testGetUrlJsonSync()
{
    var reply = getUrlJsonSync("myurl");

    if (reply.valid == 'OK')
    {
        console.dir(reply.data);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not valid');
    }    
}
```

I added the **dataType** of **'JSON'** and changed the **.responseText** to **responseJSON**.

I also retrieved the status using the **statusText** property of the returned object. Note, that this is the status of the Ajax response, not whether the JSON is valid.

The back-end has to return the response in correct (well-formed) JSON, otherwise the returned object will be undefined.

There are two aspects to consider when answering the original question. One is telling Ajax to perform synchronously (by setting **async: false**) and the other is returning the response via the calling function's return statement, rather than into a callback function.

I also tried it with POST and it worked.

I changed the GET to POST and added **data: postdata**

```
function postUrlJsonSync(url, postdata){

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false
    });

    // 'async' has to be 'false' for this to work
    var response = {valid: jqxhr.statusText,  data: jqxhr.responseJSON};

    return response;
}
```

Note that the above code only works in the case where **async** is **false**. If you were to set **async: true** the returned object **jqxhr** would not be valid at the time the AJAX call returns, only later when the asynchronous call has finished, but that is much too late to set the **response** variable.

Answer (score 14):

With `async: false` you get yourself a blocked browser.
For a non blocking synchronous solution you can use the following:

### ES6/ECMAScript2015

With ES6 you can use a generator & the [co library](https://github.com/tj/co):

```
beforecreate: function (node, targetNode, type, to) {
    co(function*(){  
        let result = yield jQuery.get('http://example.com/catalog/create/' + targetNode.id + '?name=' + encode(to.inp[0].value));
        //Just use the result here
    });
}
```

### ES7

With ES7 you can just use asyc await:

```
beforecreate: function (node, targetNode, type, to) {
    (async function(){
        let result = await jQuery.get('http://example.com/catalog/create/' + targetNode.id + '?name=' + encode(to.inp[0].value));
        //Just use the result here
    })(); 
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  async: false
}).done(function(data) {
   // Todo something..
}).fail(function(xhr)  {
   // Todo something..
});
```

Answer (score 7):

**Firstly we should understand when we use $.ajax and when we use $.get/$.post**

When we require low level control over the ajax request such as request header settings, caching settings, synchronous settings etc.then we should go for $.ajax.

$.get/$.post: When we do not require low level control over the ajax request.Only simple get/post the data to the server.**It is shorthand of**

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

and hence we can not use other features(sync,cache etc.) with $.get/$.post.

**Hence for low level control(sync,cache,etc.) over ajax request,we should go for $.ajax**

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType,
      async:false
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

this is my simple implementation for ASYNC requests with jQuery. I hope this help anyone.

```
var queueUrlsForRemove = [
    'http://dev-myurl.com/image/1', 
    'http://dev-myurl.com/image/2',
    'http://dev-myurl.com/image/3',
];

var queueImagesDelete = function(){

    deleteImage( queueUrlsForRemove.splice(0,1), function(){
        if (queueUrlsForRemove.length > 0) {
            queueImagesDelete();
        }
    });

}

var deleteImage = function(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'DELETE'
    }).done(function(response){
        typeof(callback) == 'function' ? callback(response) : null;
    });
}

queueImagesDelete();
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `XMLHttpReponse` synchronous operation is deprecated I came up with the following solution that wraps `XMLHttpRequest`. This allows ordered AJAX queries while still being asycnronous in nature, which is very useful for single use CSRF tokens.

It is also transparent so libraries such as jQuery will operate seamlessly.

```
/* wrap XMLHttpRequest for synchronous operation */
var XHRQueue = [];
var _XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function()
{
  var xhr   = new _XMLHttpRequest();
  var _send = xhr.send;

  xhr.send = function()
  {
    /* queue the request, and if it's the first, process it */
    XHRQueue.push([this, arguments]);
    if (XHRQueue.length == 1)
      this.processQueue();
  };

  xhr.processQueue = function()
  {
    var call = XHRQueue[0];
    var xhr  = call[0];
    var args = call[1];

    /* you could also set a CSRF token header here */

    /* send the request */
    _send.apply(xhr, args);
  };

  xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e)
  {
    /* you could also retrieve a CSRF token header here */

    /* remove the completed request and if there is more, trigger the next */
    XHRQueue.shift();
    if (XHRQueue.length)
      this.processQueue();
  });

  return xhr;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question was about `jQuery.get`, it is worth mentioning here that (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172561/1526703)) one **could** use `async: false` in a `$.get()` but **ideally avoid** it since asynchronous `XMLHTTPRequest` is deprecated (and the browser may give a warning):

```
$.get({
  url: url,// mandatory
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType,
  async:false // to make it synchronous
});
```